# USB won't boot - YUMI 2.0.1.0

Tags: syslinux, yumi

I recently burned Ubuntu 14.10 into an USB using YUMI on WINE. It said failed to install syslinux. I tried to put Fedora into my USB and it said good syslinux found. I restarted my PC and it said this is not a bootable device.
I also tried to install syslinux 6.03 but i have no idea what to do with syslinux.c

Answer (score 0):

Creating bootable USB media requires low-level access to them, which isn't (well) implemented in Wine for various theoretical and practical reasons.

Instead of going through Wine, you can instead [follow Canonical's official instructions to create bootable USB media in Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu).